# Cannot get component name with React.Children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I using react with nextjs framework, I try to build my own dropdown component with structure like this

```js
<Dropdown>
   <DropdownToggle>Action</DropdownToggle>
   <DropdownMenu>
      <DropdownItem>Menu 1</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>Menu 2</DropdownItem>
   </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown>
```

let's focus on dropdown children (DropdownToggle and DropdownMenu), inside dropdown component I want to pass variable `isOpen` on `DropdownMenu` and `onClick` on `DropdownToggle`, I want to check if child is a DropdownToggle or DropdownMenu component

Dropdown.tsx

```js
export const Dropdown = () => {
   const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);

   const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, child => {
      // child.type (div or button / html tag) or child.type.name (undefined)
      if (React.isValidElement(child) && child.props?.className?.includes('DropdownToggle')) {
         return React.cloneElement(child, {
           onClick: () => {
             setDropdownOpen(!dropdownOpen)
           },
         });
      }
      if (React.isValidElement(child) && child.props?.className?.includes('DropdownMenu')) {
         return React.cloneElement(child, {
           isOpen: dropdownOpen,
         });
      }
      return child;
   });
   return (
      <div className={styles.dropdown}>
         {childrenWithProps}
      </div>
   )
}
```

DropdownToggle.tsx

```js
export const DropdownToggle: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<DropdownToggleProp>> = ({onClick, children}) => {
   return (
      <button onClick={onClick}>
        {children}
      </button>
   )
}
```

DropdownMenu.tsx

```js
export const DropdownMenu: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<DropdownMenuProp>> = ({isOpen, children}) => {
   return (
      <div className={isOpen && 'open'}>
        {children}
      </div>
   )
}
```

1. I can't get the component name with `child.type` (return button or div), `child.type.name` (return undefined), `child.type.displayName` (return undefined), so I check by className
2. I got error in server and client: Warning: React does not recognize the `isOpen` prop on a DOM element. The component DropdownMenu props is not recognized, but it attached directly to DOM element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like something where a context would be easier. Then you don't need to worry at all about passing props.

For example, the `Dropdown` component can be the context provider

```tsx
interface DropdownContextValue {
  isOpen: boolean;
  toggle: () => void;
}

export const DropdownContext = createContext<DropdownContextValue>({
  isOpen: false,
  toggle: () => {}
});

// a handy custom hook
export const useDropdown = () => useContext(DropdownContext);

export const Dropdown = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => {
    setIsOpen((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <DropdownContext.Provider value={{ isOpen, toggle }}>
      <div className={styles.dropdown}>{children}</div>
    </DropdownContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

In your components, you can then use the context hook

```ts
export const DropdownToggle = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
  const { toggle } = useDropdown();
  return <button onClick={toggle}>{children}</button>;
};

export const DropdownMenu = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
  const { isOpen } = useDropdown();
  return <div className={isOpen ? "open" : ""}>{children}</div>;
};
```

[image: Edit peaceful-firefly-x6jmf7]

Comment: It works with that method, is using code bellow to close other opened dropdown correct? ` useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (event: MouseEvent) => {
      if (!ref?.current?.contains(event.target as Node)) {
        setDropdownOpen(false);
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    }
  }, [ref]);`